# Set of accumulation point of a closed set is empty

Tags: general-topology

How to prove that if $A$ is closed the set of accumulation point (the derivative) is $\emptyset$

the set of accumulation point is $A'$, we say that $x\in A'$ iff $\forall V\in \mathcal{V}_x, V\setminus\{x\}\cap A\neq \emptyset$

Where $\mathcal{V}_x$ is the sets of ngbh of $x$

Comment: how do you define an accumulation point? According to standart definition your statement is not true.

Comment: @Mihail i edited my question

Comment: Still. For A=[-1,1] which is closed, 0 is an accumulation point. So A' is not empty. Am I missing something?

Comment: why $A=\{0\}$ ?

Comment: Your statement is simply false.  It's sometimes but very rarely true but it's generally false.  A set is closed if all of it's accumulation point are in A.

Comment: I didn't say that

Comment: The only sets that have no accumulation points are vacuuously closed.  But "most" sets have accumulation points and they can be open, closed or neither.  Closed sets are sets that contain all their accumulation points.  A set with no accumulation points will be a set of isolated points.  The will be closed as all zero of the accumulation points are in the set but any set with non-isolated points will have accumulation points, including A = [0,1] which is closed and *every* point is an accumulation point.

Comment: If A = [-1,1] then A' = [-1,1] $\ne \emptyset$.  Mihail said $0 \in A'$.  S/he never said {0} = A'.  Your claim is simply .... bizarre.  It's utterly not true and I can't think of any misconception that would make one think it might be true.

Comment: What is your definition of closed.  I think you want to prove the converse.  " no accumulation points => closed."  That's trivial by my definition of closed.  ("A set is closed if all its accumulation points are contained in the set") but it can be proven with different definitions of closed.  (For example "close = its complement is open"). Either way, your statement "closed => no accumulation points"  is simply wrong. It is NOT and iff and only if statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement isn't true and it's trivial to find a counter example.  If $A = [0,1]$ then every point is an accumulation point.  $A' = [0,1] = A$.

The converse is true.  If $A$ has no accumulation points, then $A$ is closed.  For example the set {1} has no accumulation points and is closed. As is $\mathbb Z$ or any set of isolated points.

If the definition of closed is "$A$ is closed if all its accumulation points, are points of $A$" then the proof follows from definition.  If $A$ has no accumulation points, all zero of them are in A so A is closed.

If the definition of closed is "$A$ is closed if $A^c$ is open" then... Suppose $A^c$ is not open.  Then there is a point,$x$, of $A^c$ in which no neighborhood is a subset of $A^c$.  Then every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point that is not in $A^c$.  In other words every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point $y \in A$ and as $x \in A^c$ it follows $x \ne y$.  So x is an accumulation point of $A$.  Which is a contradiction of $A$ not having any accumulation points.

So $A^c$ is open, and $A$ is closed.